# sql server null value in where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, isnull

There is one table which is having only one row with 4 date columns ,initially all date value are null so

```
if Exists(select 1 from rep_master where pacdt_1=null OR
pacdt_2=null OR
pacdt_3=null OR
pacdt_4=null)
select 0
else
select 1
```

this one is returning **`1`**

```
if Exists(select 1 from rep_master where ISNULL(pacdt_1,0)=0 or
ISNULL(pacdt_2,0)=0  or
ISNULL(pacdt_3,0)=0 or
ISNULL(pacdt_4,0)=0 )
select 0
else
select 1
```

this one is returning **`0`** ,which is correct result
I m unable to figure out what is wrong with first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `IS NULL` rather than `= NULL`

so:

```
if Exists(select 1 from rep_master 
          where pacdt_1 is null OR pacdt_2 is null OR
                pacdt_3 is null OR pacdt_4 is null)
   select 0
else
   select 1
```

Comment: Yes. the result of x = NULL is UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't equal null, you have to use `IS`

```
if Exists(select 1 from rep_master where pacdt_1 IS null OR
pacdt_2 IS NULL OR
pacdt_3 IS NULL OR
pacdt_4 IS NULL)
select 0
else
select 1
```

to get where the value is not null you use `IS NOT`

```
if Exists(select 1 from rep_master where pacdt_1 IS NOT null OR
pacdt_2 IS NOT NULL OR
pacdt_3 IS NOT NULL OR
pacdt_4 IS NOT NULL)
select 0
else
select 1
```